# convert d.m.Y h:m:s to Y-d-m h:m:s for a large file in linux

Tags: linux

Is it possible to convert convert d.m.Y h:m:s to Y-d-m h:m:s for a large file in linux?

Sample data

```
"30.07.2016 00:00:00",DN123,PAPN,PAPN,TEST,918945,
```

would like to convert to

```
"2016-07-30 00:00:00",DN123,PAPN,PAPN,TEST,918945,
```

Comment: it indeed is! Please show your efforts in it, at least by checking similar examples from this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your file is called `A.csv`

Use the following:

```
awk -F","  '{print "\""substr($1,08,4)"-"substr($1,5,2)"-"substr($1,2,2)substr($1,12,9)"\","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6","}' A.csv > A.csv_new
```

You can then replace the new file with the old

```
mv A.csv_new A.csv
```

Comment: No, it should work. I have used comma as a delimiter

Comment: I would not like to specify the columns (i.e $2,$3...) . The code below works, but how do i remove the unmodified $1.                          CODE: awk -F","  '{print "\""substr($1,08,4)"-"substr($1,5,2)"-"substr($1,2,2)substr($1,12,9)"\","$0""}' file.csv

Comment: @SantoshPillai what do you mean by remove the unmodified $1?
Thing is date manipulation is not native to bash, hence the workaround

Comment: If you execute the code in my comment. awk first prints the modified dateTime and then prints $0 which is everything including the unmodified dateTime. How do I get rid of the unmodified dateTime?  I have a bunch of files where the same manipulation is required and the files have different field lengths. It would have been nice to have one code which works for all

Comment: I understood what you're trying to achieve. I'm sorry but it can't work that way - you will have to print the rest of the $2, $3 and so on.